# How to obtain the value of another element to send email via Contact Forms 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a team list set up and the idea is a user can select a team member and they will be taken to another page with their details. We have a button on that page which pops up a Contact Forms 7 form to send them an email.
The issue I'm having is being able to obtain the team members email to send the email to them.

The current set up for the form is below:

```
<label> 
    [text* your-name placeholder "Your name"] </label>

<label> 
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email placeholder "From (your email address)"] </label>

<label> 
    [text* your-subject placeholder "Subject"] </label>

<label> 
    [textarea* your-message placeholder "Message*"] </label>

[hidden staff-member]




[submit class:bg-primary "Send"]
```

I then try to pass [staff-member] in the "To" field in Mail tab, but this doesn't work.

I tried adding [email* staff-member default:get], but I still get an empty field.

Is there a way to dynamically set the "To" field with whoever the team member we try to contact?